# Visual Studio configures my local IIS website as an ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, web, vs-web-site-project

We are using Visual Studio 2008 on IIS 7, and on some machines we are having trouble getting Visual Studio to recognize our website as an IIS website. On most machines it is configured properly, displaying and running under http://localhost/websitename. But on a couple of machines - using the same solution file - it loads it as a directory/asp.net site: in VS it appears as c:...\foldername, and when running it, it comes up as http://localhost:randomportnumber/websitename.

We tried removing and then re-adding the site through the File-> Open Website-> Local IIS, but when we select the site it automatically changes it to a asp.net site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Service Pack 1 on VS 2008 on all machines? All computer running the same OS? I am sure someone can help with a little more information.

Comment: Is it that you're not sure why it's running in different ways on different machines? Or are you changing the projects to point to IIS and it's still not working?

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner (I thought I had it set up to email me when comments/answers were added), in any case... John: I'm pretty sure we are all running SP1, but I'll double check. Schnapple: Both true - why is it behaving differently on different machines, and why is it that when we try to change the project for those machine to point to IIS it doesn't help....makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the project, you can specify whether or not to use IIS or the built-in ASP.NET server.

Answer (score 0):

When you debug a website and you see the odd port number after local, you are running the visual studio web server Cassini and not through IIS.

You can configure this when you go to property settings on your website.

Comment: Tried changing the propery settings to no avail...thanks for the suggestion though